# jQuery preg replace

Tags: jquery, html, regex, replace, match

Hi again dear comminity!

To make it short, I have a textbox, where you can paste `<img>` tags, which look like this:
`<img src="123.jpg" />`.

Is there any way to make these `<img>` look this: `<img src="img/upload/username/123.jpg" />` using jQuery `.replace()` or something like this ? Or should I use PHP function instead ?

I have tried to find out what jQuery `.match()` returns for some regual expression:

```
x = text.match(/\<img src="(.*)" \/>\$/);
alert(x);
```

,but it returns odd things, when there are more than one `<img>` tag.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, maybe I'm saying something wrong, but still is there any way to transform one src to another using javascript for all the specified "img" tags ?

Comment: you are looking for post 6572214 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested...

```
$('#text').change(function(){

    $('img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', '/img/upload/username/' + $(this).attr('src'));
    });

});
```

If you would like to do this on server side with PHP you can just replace like this, no need for regex...

```
$text = str_replace('src="', 'src="/img/upload/username/', $text);
```

Or if you would like to use regexp...

```
$text = preg_replace('#"(.*?)\.jpg"#is', '"/img/upload/username/\\1.jpg"', $text);
```

Comment: Damn, genious solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dmitri, no problem, try replacing `$('img')` with eg `$('#preview img')`, otherwise it will replace all images on page ;)

Answer (score 1):

The function you would like to use in jquery is .attr() and replace the content with whatever you like. Here is the tutorial page: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thank you too! Why didn't I thought of that in first place

Answer (score 1):

> but it returns odd things, when there are more than one  tag.

I think it's the problem that you are not using a lazy match. Instead of `(.*)` use `(.*?)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var text    =   '<img src="img/upload/username/123.jpg" />';
x = text.match(/\<img src="(.*)" \/\>$/);
alert(x);
```

now u ll get??

```
match(/\<img src="(.*)" \/\>$/);
                          ^
                          |-----------------Becarefull about about ur special char dude....
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work well when there are more than 1 "img" tag!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex returns not what you expect with more than one tag, because you use a greedy quantifier here:

```
x = text.match(/\<img src="(.*)" \/>\$/);
                             ^
```

To fix this try this:

```
x = text.match(/\<img src="(.*?)" \/>\$/);
```

I am not sure about your escaping ... . Normally you don't need to escape `<` and I also don't understand what the `\$` is good for at the end. It is not in your string. If you want to have a anchor for string end then don't escape it, but if you want to be able to insert multiple tags, you can't use it at all.